# White preview of non-white dds texture in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, dds-format

I imported a texture to Unity, but it's preview shows, that it's full white, while it obviously doesn't. When I create a material from it, it stays white.
What can I do, and why does this happen? :D
Thanks for your further help.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I converted it to PNG, and now it's fine.
But I am curious :D Why did that happen?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue with a photoshop file that I stored as PSD without the "maximum file compatibility" option using Photoshop CC 2015. Unity imported the texture just as white, so apparently it was unable to read it.

The Unity Guide says this about [**Supported Formats**](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html)

> Unity can read the following file formats: PSD, TIFF, JPG, TGA, PNG,
>   GIF, BMP, IFF, PICT. It should be noted that Unity can import
>   multi-layer PSD and TIFF files just fine. They are flattened
>   automatically on import but the layers are maintained in the assets
>   themselves, so you don’t lose any of your work when using these file
>   types natively. This is important as it allows you to just have one
>   copy of your textures that you can use from Photoshop, through your 3D
>   modelling app and into Unity.

The DDS format seems not to be supported.